# Splitting a PDF into pages of different lengths

Tags: .net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, pdfsharp

I need to be able to separate a large scanned pdf image file which consists of many documents of differing lengths into separate PDF files.

I know one way of doing this is by including a separator page inbetween each document before scanning all the documents in one go. Typically this is done by using a barcode on a separator page which is read and then a new PDF file is created when detected.

I would prefer to be do this in .net but am open to other suggestions. I have had a look on this site at a couple of popular libaries - itextsharp and pdfsharp. I have not been able to find any examples where a PDF file is being split into smaller PDFs of differing number of pages only fixed lengths.

I am not sure it is possible with these libaries, does anyone have any ideas of an alternative   or if it is possible?

Comment: Pretty much every PDF library out there should be able to split a PDF into multiple pages for you. You will need to provide the logic, however, on what pages should go in what files.

Comment: You are looking at two libraries designed to create PDF.  They may have it.  This is not free but Aspose.BarCode for .NET but it has creation and detection.

Comment: I did see the Aspose.Barcode library. Ideally I would like something that is free if possible. It doesn't have to be a barcode on the separator sheet, just some sort of template that when scanned will be recognised as the signal that the start of a differnet document is next.

Answer (score 1):

I am in a same situation and found a solution provided by [ByteScout](https://bytescout.com/download/download_freeware.html)

The sample code after downloading BarCodeReader.dll will be

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Bytescout.BarCodeReader;

namespace SplitByBarcode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputFile = @"abc.pdf";

            Console.WriteLine("Processing file " + inputFile);

            using (Reader reader = new Reader())
            {
                reader.RegistrationName = "demo";
                reader.RegistrationKey = "demo";

                reader.BarcodeTypesToFind.Code128 = true; // EAN-128 is the same as Code 128
                reader.PDFRenderingResolution = 96;

                FoundBarcode[] barcodes = reader.ReadFrom(inputFile);
                Console.WriteLine("Found " + barcodes.Length + " barcodes");

                if (barcodes.Length > 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder pageRanges = new StringBuilder();

                    // Create string containing page ranges to extract in the form "1-4,6-8,10-11,12-"
                    for (int i = 0; i < barcodes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        FoundBarcode barcode = barcodes[i];
                        pageRanges.Append(barcode.Page + 2); // +1 because we skip the page with barcode and another +1 because need 1-based page numbers
                        pageRanges.Append("-");
                        if (i < barcodes.Length - 1)
                        {
                            pageRanges.Append(barcodes[i + 1].Page);
                            pageRanges.Append(",");
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Extracting page ranges " + pageRanges);

                    // Split document 
                    string[] splittedParts = reader.SplitDocument(inputFile, pageRanges.ToString());

                    // Rename parts according to barcode values
                    for (int i = 0; i < splittedParts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string fileName = barcodes[i].Value + ".pdf";

                        File.Delete(fileName);
                        File.Move(splittedParts[i], fileName);

                        Console.WriteLine("Saved file " + fileName);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you want to do, but this is one way to read a file `src`, select page 1-10, and create a file `dest` with only those pages:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
reader.SelectPages("1-10");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
stamper.Close();
```

An alternative would be to use `PdfCopy`. Again you create a reader object:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
```

Now you can use this reader object to create different files, where `start` and `end` are the page number where you want to start and end.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
using (Document document = new Document()) {
    using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, fs)) {
        document.Open();
        for (int i = start; i < end;) {
            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i++));
        }
    }
}
```

This is all documented in my book, more specifically in [chapter 6 (free download)](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf).

As you can choose the range of pages, you can split a document with X pages into Y documents with a different number of pages. Obviously, you have to define the number of pages of each separate document yourself. Libraries such as iTextSharp, PdfSharp, etc... see every scanned page as an image and they don't interpret what's on that page. Introducing a page with a barcode doesn't really make sense. However: if you'd add an annotation on each first page (an annotation is an interactive object in the PDF, **not** something you add to a page), then iText could split the document based on the places where such an annotation is found.

Comment: How would you add an annotation at the first page of each document?  If I can do this then surely I know where the start of each document is and can just split the batch scan instead.

Are there any free libraries that do try and detect what is on each page or are we looking at commercial products for that?

Comment: Adding comments (a special type of annotations) is now possible with Adobe Reader. When you say you want to detect what is on each page: most libraries can detect annotations; most of them can detect the presence of an image; hardly any can detect the content of the images (I don't know any). Note that iText is commercial open source software: it's free software, but not gratis software. You can use it without paying a fee if you follow the rules of the AGPL. If you don't, there's a license fee to be paid.